# Change regionprops orientation range

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using matlab to track the orientation of rotating object, whose position is retrieved at each step by a camera sensor. This is the image I'm talking about:

[image: camera]

The object moves back and forth rotating on its joint.

I am using regionprops on the image in order to get the angle, however it is my understanding that regionprops works in the range [-90, 90] degrees and computes the angle between the major axis of the ellipsoid encapsulating the area and the x-axis. This is unfortunate, because this is what I get (upper image) compared to what it should look like (lower image).

[image: angles]

Is there any way to change the range of regionprops so that it is [0 360]? If not, what can I use instead? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: If push comes to shove you can always try [`unwrap`ping](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) your data (or doing an equivalent correction with `pi` periodicity) to get a smooth curve. Of course you'll want to make sure that jumps you find are really only artifacts from this behaviour of regionprops. Or perhaps you can identify the orientation yourself, like measuring the position of the black spot with respect to the centroid of the region. Then you can correct the 180-degree ambiguity in the angle.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thank you for your reply. Sounds like a good way (they are indeed artifacts). Is there any way to do it in real time?

Comment: You always have to compare an angle to the angle in a previous time step, so I see no reason why it shouldn't work in real time (whatever you may mean by that exactly ;)

Comment: Actually, there's more than just the phase jump problem. Look at your initial point: your orientation is 0, but regionprops gives you 90. This means that the result of regionprops is perpendicular to your expected orientation, which can't be explained by the pi periodicity of what `regionprops` gives you (i.e. basically the difference between `atan` and `atan2`).